# While compiling Java+Scala project got java.lang.AssertionError: NoDenotation.owner

Tags: java, scala, gradle, groovy

That's my project on writing the Minecraft plugin using **Scala** as the main language, supported by **Java**. I'm using **Gradle** and some settings *to combine* **Scala and Java**.
I've had a working prototype of one of the modules and then added some refactoring, that somehow called the exception. As far as I've researched, there are only 3 to 8 results on the search, related to the **"NoDenotation.owner"** exception. Now I have no idea how to resolve it and there are no comments on it on the StackOverflow as well.

Here is my build.gradle file (I'll fix shadowing part later):

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'scala'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.2'
}

group = 'com.danikvitek'
version = '1.0'

sourceSets {
    main {
        scala.srcDirs = ["$projectDir/src/main/mixed"]
        resources.srcDirs = ["$projectDir/src/main/resources"]
    }
    test {
        scala.srcDirs = ["$projectDir/src/test/mixed"]
        resources.srcDirs = ["$projectDir/src/test/resources"]
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = 'papermc-repo'
        url = 'https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/'
    }
    maven {
        name = 'sonatype'
        url = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/'
    }
    maven {
        name = 'codemc-snapshots'
        url = 'https://repo.codemc.io/repository/maven-snapshots/'
    }
    maven { url "https://repo.dmulloy2.net/repository/public/" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.3.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.6.3.Final'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.25'
    implementation 'net.wesjd:anvilgui:1.5.3-SNAPSHOT'
    compileOnly 'io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.17.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
//    compileOnly group: "com.comphenix.protocol", name: "ProtocolLib", version: "4.7.0";
    compileOnly group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala3-library_3', version: '3.1.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala3-library_3', version: '3.1.0'
}

jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

def targetJavaVersion = 16
java {
    def javaVersion = JavaVersion.toVersion(targetJavaVersion)
    sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
    targetCompatibility = javaVersion
    if (JavaVersion.current() < javaVersion) {
        toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(targetJavaVersion)
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    if (targetJavaVersion >= 10 || JavaVersion.current().isJava10Compatible()) {
        options.release = targetJavaVersion
    }
}

processResources {
    def props = [version: version]
    inputs.properties props
    filteringCharset 'UTF-8'
    filesMatching('plugin.yml') {
        expand props
    }
}
```

And here is the exception stacktrace:

```
## Exception when compiling 84 sources to D:\Desktop\Minecraft plugins\PoliticsCountryS\build\classes\scala\main
java.lang.AssertionError: NoDenotation.owner
dotty.tools.dotc.core.SymDenotations$NoDenotation$.owner(SymDenotations.scala:2503)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.canAssign$1(Typer.scala:959)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedAssign(Typer.scala:996)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedUnnamed$1(Typer.scala:2762)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedUnadapted(Typer.scala:2818)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typed(Typer.scala:2883)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typed(Typer.scala:2887)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.traverse$1(Typer.scala:2936)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedStats(Typer.scala:2959)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedBlockStats(Typer.scala:1027)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedBlock(Typer.scala:1031)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedUnnamed$1(Typer.scala:2763)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedUnadapted(Typer.scala:2818)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.ProtoTypes$FunProto.$anonfun$5(ProtoTypes.scala:431)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.ProtoTypes$FunProto.cacheTypedArg(ProtoTypes.scala:359)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.ProtoTypes$FunProto.typedArg(ProtoTypes.scala:432)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications$ApplyToUntyped.typedArg(Applications.scala:853)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications$ApplyToUntyped.typedArg(Applications.scala:853)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications$Application.addTyped$1(Applications.scala:544)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications$Application.matchArgs(Applications.scala:609)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications$Application.matchArgs(Applications.scala:609)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications$Application.matchArgs(Applications.scala:609)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications$Application.init(Applications.scala:447)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications$TypedApply.<init>(Applications.scala:735)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications$ApplyToUntyped.<init>(Applications.scala:852)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications.ApplyTo(Applications.scala:1060)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications.ApplyTo$(Applications.scala:317)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.ApplyTo(Typer.scala:107)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications.simpleApply$1(Applications.scala:907)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications.realApply$5$$anonfun$4(Applications.scala:986)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.tryEither(Typer.scala:3011)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications.realApply$1(Applications.scala:997)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications.typedApply(Applications.scala:1035)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Applications.typedApply$(Applications.scala:317)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedApply(Typer.scala:107)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedUnnamed$1(Typer.scala:2755)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedUnadapted(Typer.scala:2818)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typed(Typer.scala:2883)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typed(Typer.scala:2887)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedExpr(Typer.scala:3003)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedParent$2(Typer.scala:2321)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.$anonfun$40(Typer.scala:2396)
dotty.tools.dotc.core.Decorators$ListDecorator$.loop$1(Decorators.scala:92)
dotty.tools.dotc.core.Decorators$ListDecorator$.mapconserve$extension(Decorators.scala:108)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedClassDef(Typer.scala:2396)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedTypeOrClassDef$2(Typer.scala:2743)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedNamed$1(Typer.scala:2747)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedUnadapted(Typer.scala:2817)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typed(Typer.scala:2883)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typed(Typer.scala:2887)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.traverse$1(Typer.scala:2909)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedStats(Typer.scala:2959)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedPackageDef(Typer.scala:2532)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedUnnamed$1(Typer.scala:2788)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedUnadapted(Typer.scala:2818)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typed(Typer.scala:2883)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typed(Typer.scala:2887)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.Typer.typedExpr(Typer.scala:3003)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.TyperPhase.liftedTree1$1(TyperPhase.scala:56)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.TyperPhase.typeCheck$$anonfun$1(TyperPhase.scala:62)
dotty.tools.dotc.core.Phases$Phase.monitor(Phases.scala:411)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.TyperPhase.typeCheck(TyperPhase.scala:63)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.TyperPhase.runOn$$anonfun$1(TyperPhase.scala:105)
scala.runtime.function.JProcedure1.apply(JProcedure1.java:15)
scala.runtime.function.JProcedure1.apply(JProcedure1.java:10)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
dotty.tools.dotc.typer.TyperPhase.runOn(TyperPhase.scala:105)
dotty.tools.dotc.Run.runPhases$4$$anonfun$4(Run.scala:261)
scala.runtime.function.JProcedure1.apply(JProcedure1.java:15)
scala.runtime.function.JProcedure1.apply(JProcedure1.java:10)
scala.collection.ArrayOps$.foreach$extension(ArrayOps.scala:1323)
dotty.tools.dotc.Run.runPhases$5(Run.scala:272)
dotty.tools.dotc.Run.compileUnits$$anonfun$1(Run.scala:280)
scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
dotty.tools.dotc.util.Stats$.maybeMonitored(Stats.scala:68)
dotty.tools.dotc.Run.compileUnits(Run.scala:289)
dotty.tools.dotc.Run.compileSources(Run.scala:222)
dotty.tools.dotc.Run.compile(Run.scala:206)
dotty.tools.dotc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:39)
dotty.tools.dotc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:199)
dotty.tools.dotc.Main.process(Main.scala)
xsbt.CachedCompilerImpl.run(CachedCompilerImpl.java:67)
xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.java:59)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:248)
sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:122)
sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:95)
sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:91)
scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:186)
sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3$adapted(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
sbt.internal.inc.JarUtils$.withPreviousJar(JarUtils.scala:215)
sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:146)
sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)
sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)
sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.doCompile(Incremental.scala:120)
sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$4(Incremental.scala:100)
sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.recompileClasses(IncrementalCommon.scala:180)
sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:98)
sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$3(Incremental.scala:102)
sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:155)
sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:92)
sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:75)
sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:348)
sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:301)
sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:168)
sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:248)
sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:74)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.ZincScalaCompiler.execute(ZincScalaCompiler.java:157)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.ZincScalaCompilerFacade.execute(ZincScalaCompilerFacade.java:47)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.ZincScalaCompilerFacade.execute(ZincScalaCompilerFacade.java:32)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkAction.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:135)
org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:49)
org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker.executeInClassLoader(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.run(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:49)
org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.run(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:30)
org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:85)
org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:55)
org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction$1.call(WorkerAction.java:138)
org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.WorkerLogEventListener.withWorkerLoggingProtocol(WorkerLogEventListener.java:41)
org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:135)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Here are the places, where the new code was added:

PMenuCommand.scala:

```
package com.danikvitek.politicscountry.ui.command

import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.ui.gui.prefab.PMenu
import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.ui.gui.{Menu, MenuHandler}
import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.utils.Translation
import org.bukkit.{Bukkit, ChatColor}
import org.bukkit.command.{Command, CommandSender, TabExecutor}
import org.bukkit.entity.Player
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory

import java.util

class PMenuCommand extends TabExecutor {
    override def onCommand(sender: CommandSender, command: Command,
                           alias: String, args: Array[String]): Boolean = {
        sender match {
            case player: Player =>
                if player hasPermission "politicscountry.command.pmenu" then {
                    val menu: Menu = new PMenu(player)
                    MenuHandler.openMenu(player, menu)
                }
                else
                    player sendMessage Translation.`you have no permission to use this command`
            case _ => sender sendMessage (ChatColor.RED.toString + "You need to be a player to use this command")
        }
        true
    }

    override def onTabComplete(sender: CommandSender, command: Command,
                               alias: String, args: Array[String]): util.List[String] = {
        new util.ArrayList[String]
    }
}
```

PMenu.scala:

```
package com.danikvitek.politicscountry.ui.gui.prefab

import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.ui.gui.{Button, Menu, MenuHandler}
import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.utils.{ItemBuilder, Translation}
import org.bukkit.{Bukkit, ChatColor, Material}
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent
import org.bukkit.inventory.{Inventory, ItemStack}
import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.api.controller.{FormationManager, ResidentManager}
import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.RichPlayer
import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.gameplay.residency.Resident
import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component
import net.wesjd.anvilgui.AnvilGUI
import org.bukkit.entity.Player

import scala.collection.mutable

class PMenu(player: Player)
    extends DoubleChestMenu(Component.text(Translation.`pmenu inventory title`)) {

    private lazy val resident = player.toResident

    private lazy val statusButton = new Button(Material.RED_STAINED_GLASS_PANE, Translation.`status`) {
        override def onClick(menu: Menu, event: InventoryClickEvent): Unit = {
            event setCancelled true

            val statusMenu: Menu = new Status(resident)

            MenuHandler.closeMenu(player)
            MenuHandler.openMenu(player, statusMenu)
        }
    }

    private lazy val createFormationButton = new Button(Material.RED_STAINED_GLASS_PANE, Translation.`create formation`) {
        override def onClick(menu: Menu, event: InventoryClickEvent): Unit = {
            event setCancelled true

            var title: String = null

            new AnvilGUI.Builder()
                .title(Translation.`create formation`)
                .itemLeft(new ItemStack(Material.PAPER))
                .text(Translation.`input formation title`)
                .onClose { p =>
                    MenuHandler.closeMenu(p)
                    p.performCommand("pmenu")
                }
                .onComplete { (p, t) =>
                    title = t
                    AnvilGUI.Response.close()
                }
                .open(player)

            val chunk = player.getLocation.getChunk()
            FormationManager.create(title, chunk, resident)
        }
    }

    setButton(24, statusButton)

    if resident.feud.isEmpty then
        setButton(13, createFormationButton)
}
```

SingleChestMenu.scala:

```
package com.danikvitek.politicscountry.ui.gui.prefab

import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.ui.gui.{Button, Menu}
import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.utils.Translation
import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component
import org.bukkit.{Bukkit, Material}
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent

abstract class SingleChestMenu(title: Component)
    extends Menu(Bukkit.createInventory(null, 27, title)) {

    def this(title: String) = this(Component.text(title))

    for {
        slot <- Seq(0, 1, 7, 8, 18, 19, 25, 26)
    } setButton(slot, new Button(Material.BLUE_STAINED_GLASS_PANE, " ") {
        override def onClick(menu: Menu, event: InventoryClickEvent): Unit = event setCancelled true
    })
}
```

DoubleChestMenu.scala:

```
package com.danikvitek.politicscountry.ui.gui.prefab

import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.ui.gui.{Button, Menu}
import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.utils.Translation
import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent
import org.bukkit.{Bukkit, Material}

abstract class DoubleChestMenu(title: Component)
    extends Menu(Bukkit.createInventory(null, 54, title)) {

    def this(title: String) = this(Component text title)

    for {
        slot <- Seq(0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 17, 36, 44, 45, 46, 47, 51, 52, 53)
    } setButton(slot, new Button(Material.BLUE_STAINED_GLASS_PANE, " ") {
        override def onClick(menu: Menu, event: InventoryClickEvent): Unit = event setCancelled true
    })
}
```

Status.scala:

```
package com.danikvitek.politicscountry.ui.gui.prefab

import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.gameplay.residency.Resident
import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.ui.gui.{Button, Menu, MenuHandler}
import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.utils.{ItemBuilder, Translation}
import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.api.controller.ResidentManager
import com.danikvitek.politicscountry.data.model.FormationType
import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component
import net.kyori.adventure.text.format.{NamedTextColor, TextColor}
import net.kyori.adventure.util.RGBLike
import org.bukkit.{Bukkit, ChatColor, Material}
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent

class Status(resident: Resident) extends SingleChestMenu(Translation.`status`) {

    private val residentStatus = resident.getStatus

    setButton(11, new Button(
        new ItemBuilder(Material.RED_STAINED_GLASS_PANE)
            .setDisplayName(Translation.`status - resident role`)
            .addLore(Translation.`status - resident role map`(residentStatus._1))
            .build
    ) {
        override def onClick(menu: Menu, event: InventoryClickEvent): Unit = event setCancelled true
    })

    setButton(13, new Button(
        new ItemBuilder(Material.RED_STAINED_GLASS_PANE)
            .setDisplayName(Translation.`status - formation`)
            .setLore {
                val feud = residentStatus._2
                val commonwealth = residentStatus._3
                val state = residentStatus._4
                val alliance = residentStatus._5

                var lore = List.empty[String]
                feud foreach { f =>
                    val typeName = f.typeName
                        .getOrElse(Translation.`status - formation type map`(FormationType.FEUD))
                    lore = lore :+
                        (Translation.`status - formation type color` + typeName + ": " + f.title)
                }
                commonwealth foreach { c =>
                    val typeName = c.typeName
                        .getOrElse(Translation.`status - formation type map`(FormationType.COMMONWEALTH))
                    lore = lore :+
                        (Translation.`status - formation type color` + typeName + ": " + c.title)
                }
                state foreach { s =>
                    val typeName = s.typeName
                        .getOrElse(Translation.`status - formation type map`(FormationType.STATE))
                    lore = lore :+
                        (Translation.`status - formation type color` + typeName + ": " + s.title)
                }
                alliance foreach { a =>
                    val typeName = a.typeName
                        .getOrElse(Translation.`status - formation type map`(FormationType.ALLIANCE))
                    lore = lore :+
                        (Translation.`status - formation type color` + typeName + ": " + a.title)
                }
                if lore.sizeIs == 0 then lore = lore :+
                    (Translation.`status - formation type color` + Translation.`status - formation type nothing`)

                lore
            }
            .build
    ) {
        override def onClick(menu: Menu, event: InventoryClickEvent): Unit = event setCancelled true
    })

    setButton(15, new Button(
        new ItemBuilder(Material.RED_STAINED_GLASS_PANE)
            .setDisplayName(Translation.`status - resident plots`)
            .setLore {
                val distances = residentStatus._6
                    .toSeq
                    .map { rp =>
                        val homePlotChunk = resident.feud.get.homePlot.chunk
                        math.hypot(homePlotChunk.getX - rp.chunk.getX, homePlotChunk.getZ - rp.chunk.getZ)
                    }
                val chunks = residentStatus._6
                    .toSeq
                    .map(_.chunk)
                var plotsList = (distances zip chunks)
                    .sortWith(_._1 < _._1)
                    .map(_._2)
                    .map { chunk =>
                        Translation.`status - resident plot color` + Translation.`status - plot at` +
                            s" (${chunk.getX}, ${chunk.getZ})"
                    }

                if plotsList.sizeIs == 0 then plotsList = plotsList :+
                    (Translation.`status - resident plot color` + Translation.`status - no plots`)

                plotsList
            }
            .build
    ) {
        override def onClick(menu: Menu, event: InventoryClickEvent): Unit = event setCancelled true
    })

    setButton(19, new Button(
        Material.YELLOW_STAINED_GLASS_PANE,
        Translation.`menu - back`
    ) {
        override def onClick(menu: Menu, event: InventoryClickEvent): Unit = {
            event setCancelled true

            val player = resident.player
            MenuHandler closeMenu player
            player performCommand "pmenu"
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve it?

Comment: To be honest, no. What's really weird is that I've just rewritten the class again and the problem was solved. Some bug in the Scala itself, probably

Comment: Hey, the issue was because of dependency injection for me.. When I added few other scala plugins and updated versions, the issue got resolved. Same might have happened in your case probably.